# Trying to install Mysql on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

I am currenty trying to install MySql on my Ubuntu 12.04 server.
But I got problems, When i run `sudo apt-get install mysql-server` it runs, ask me for a Yes but then.
It returns Temporart failure resolving, Failed to fetch.
I am using PuTTY to manage the server, but I can access it physically.
This is what I get when i run the command.

```
root@cloud:/home/tek/openstackgeek# sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient18
  libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
  mysql-common mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
Suggested packages:
  libipc-sharedcache-perl libterm-readkey-perl tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient18
  libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5
  mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 27.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 97.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main mysql-common all 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Temporary failure resolving âno.archive.ubuntu.comâ
Err http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libnet-daemon-perl all 0.48-1
  Temporary failure resolving âno.archive.ubuntu.comâ
Err http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libplrpc-perl all 0.2020-2
  Temporary failure resolving âno.archive.ubuntu.comâ
Err http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libdbi-perl amd64 1.616-1build2
  Temporary failure resolving âno.archive.ubuntu.comâ
Err http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libdbd-mysql-perl amd64 4.020-1build2
  Temporary failure resolving âno.archive.ubuntu.comâ
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main mysql-common all 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Temporary failure resolving âsecurity.ubuntu.comâ
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main libmysqlclient18 amd64 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Temporary failure resolving âsecurity.ubuntu.comâ
Err http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libhtml-template-perl all 2.10-1
  Temporary failure resolving âno.archive.ubuntu.comâ
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main mysql-client-core-5.5 amd64 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Temporary failure resolving âsecurity.ubuntu.comâ
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main mysql-client-5.5 amd64 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Temporary failure resolving âsecurity.ubuntu.comâ
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main mysql-server-core-5.5 amd64 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Temporary failure resolving âsecurity.ubuntu.comâ
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main mysql-server-5.5 amd64 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Temporary failure resolving âsecurity.ubuntu.comâ
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main mysql-server all 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
  Temporary failure resolving âsecurity.ubuntu.comâ
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-common_5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving âsecurity.ubuntu.comâ
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/libmysqlclient18_5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving âsecurity.ubuntu.comâ
Failed to fetch http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnet-daemon-perl/libnet-daemon-perl_0.48-1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving âno.archive.ubuntu.comâ
Failed to fetch http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libplrpc-perl/libplrpc-perl_0.2020-2_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving âno.archive.ubuntu.comâ
Failed to fetch http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libd/libdbi-perl/libdbi-perl_1.616-1build2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving âno.archive.ubuntu.comâ
Failed to fetch http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libd/libdbd-mysql-perl/libdbd-mysql-perl_4.020-1build2_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving âno.archive.ubuntu.comâ
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving âsecurity.ubuntu.comâ
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving âsecurity.ubuntu.comâ
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving âsecurity.ubuntu.comâ
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving âsecurity.ubuntu.comâ
Failed to fetch http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libh/libhtml-template-perl/libhtml-template-perl_2.10-1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving âno.archive.ubuntu.comâ
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-server_5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving âsecurity.ubuntu.comâ
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I am trying to install OpenStack on the server, and came to the Mysql step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can resolve security.ubuntu.com so you may have limited network connectivity or your name resolution is incorrectly configured. Make sure you have valid nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf` and DNS is enabled on the hosts line of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. Then try pinging www.yahoo.com.

Comment: Looks like the problem was limited network connectivity, tried to ping before I changed it, No response, after I did what you said, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a problem with the repository your are actually using.

Use [this site](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) to generate a new `sources.list`and paste it in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

After that `sudo apt-get update` to refresh the package list and try installing mysql-server again.